# Unable to install airflow-pentaho-plugin python package using PIP

Tags: airflow, python-3.9

I'm trying to install a python package airflow-pentaho-plugin, I'm getting the following error. I'm also trying to use Python setup.py install command and the error still remains the same. Request you to help me unblock this installation process.

- Environment - Python3.9
- Pip version - 21.0.1
- OS- Linux - RHEL (6.9)
- Command - sudo pip install airflow-pentaho-plugin --proxy=http://proxy:port
- Error - ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement setuptools-git-version

I've also run the `requires.txt` and I see the following message when I rerun:

```
Requirement already satisfied: xmltodict>=0.10.0 in /usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from -r requires.txt (line 1)) (0.12.0)
```

Could you please let me know what am I missing here?

Comment: Could you provide some more information with a pip  and exact error messages? Tip: you can format code between two `. It makes your post more readable.

Comment: Please add it to your post as text. I am not willing to download anything I don't know.